# How to get the <p> where the cursor is in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DIV element with contenteditable="true".
As i write text into this div i get multiple

elements.

Here is an example [link](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable).

**Question**

> How can I get the
>
> element which contains the cursor?
>   And it would be extra nice to be able to obtain the index position of the cursor (in a cross-browser supportive way).

Thanks!

**Updated**
By cursor index position, i don't necessarily mean X, Y coordinates. I mean string index position of a sentence, for instance.

Comment: Have you tried with `is:focus` ? This could be a good starting point I think.

Comment: JSfiddle using focus checking: http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/C98gm/1/

Comment: @Smokey. This is an answer. please "answer" this question. Thanks.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Was only part of your question, but indeed most other questions are only tackling the main part, I've added my answer with a quick note about your 'would be nice' as per cursor position/index.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like that? 
**HTML**

```
<section contenteditable="true" id="editable">
  <h2>Go ahead, edit away!</h2>
  <p>Here's a typical paragraph element</p>
  <ol>
    <li>and now a list</li>
    <li>with only</li>
    <li>three items</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

**JS Code**:

```
$('#editable').mousemove(function(e){
    console.log(e.target.nodeName);
    console.log(e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY);
});
```

**NOTE**: You could also change `mousemove` event to what ever you want, as an example: `click`, `hover` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think usual nodes (basically non input nodes) do not have a focused flag. But before you can write into an element you have to do a click into it. You can hook into the click event to get the node.

(e.g. with jQuery:

```
$('document').on('click', function() {
    console.log('you have clicked on: ', $(this));
});
```

)

Comment: Not necessarily true about the click. There could be a TAB and/or arrow keys involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine doing something like:

```
var hovered;
$('div[contenteditable] *').bind('mouseenter.editable', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  hovered = this;

  console.log(this);
  console.log($(this).index());
  console.log(e.pageX);
  console.log(e.pageY);
});
```

Just have a global variable that gets changed upon hover, `stopPropagation()` to make sure no parent element "takes the credit", and you get to play with `this`, `e.pageX`, `e.pageY` with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `onMouseOver` attributes to containers, making them run a code that changes some variable for example. You could use also `onMouseOut` attributes to remove the value from the variable when the mouse exits the container.

This is a sample of that code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Example page</title>
       <script src="your/script/path.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <p id="1" onMouseOver="setParagraph(this)">Example paragraph 1</p>
       <p id="2" onMouseOver="setParagraph(this)">Example paragraph 2</p>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Javascript:

```
var mouseOverParagraph,
    setParagraph = function (el) {
      'use strict';
      mouseOverParagraph = el.id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery focus selector to find which element has the cursor focus:

```
var focusedP = null;
$(document).on("focus","p[contenteditable]",function(){
    focusedP = $(this);
})
$(document).on("blur","p[contenteditable]",function(){
    focusedP = null;
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/C98gm/1/)

As for cursor position within the element, I can't say, but you might be able to work out what character was originally clicked by capturing the mouse click and getting the relative coords. With a static font size and line height, you could calculate from the coords what line and character it was at.